# Need Solution on NicEdit Insert HTML text into Instance

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, nicedit

i am using this function to insert text into NicEdit,

```
function insertAtCursor(editor, value){
var editor = nicEditors.findEditor(editor);
var range = editor.getRng();                    
var editorField = editor.selElm();
editorField.nodeValue = editorField.nodeValue.substring(0, range.startOffset) +
                        value +
                        editorField.nodeValue.substring(range.endOffset, editorField.nodeValue.length);}
```

**This code works fine for simple text but when i pass HTML content into it, it does not render the HTML output in div instead it dumps the HTML code as it is into the Instance Div.**

***Example:***

```
<div class="one">Some text here</div>
```

This must show in the Instance as **"Some text here"**
and remaining code hidden in source code.

Can any one give me a solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working whole night and trying different solutions I had finally got it working! :)

In case any one wants to know solution for this, I had to add a Replace function

```
replace()
```

for the content and made it support HTML.

Comment: facing similar issue...could you pls elaborate?
My code
 if (this.options.command == 'InsertBookmark') {
            var editor = nicEditors.findEditor("cpMain_area2");
            var range = editor.getRng();            
            var editorField = editor.selElm();
            alert(A);
            if (editorField.nodeValue == null) {
              //  editorField.setContent('"' + A + '"')
                editorField.replacew(A);
              //  editorField.replace(A,'<br/>');
          //      editorField.insertBefore("<DIV>tEST</DIV>", editor.selElm())
          }

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869304/1742621). It's a plugin I created to insert html at the cursor position.